# How to build spp-net in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

since tf.max_pool dosen't support variable size, the spp layer does not work. 
I feed the length to the graph, got a error.

```
length = tf.placeholder(tf.int32)
shape=[-1, length,length,32]
pool = tf.nn.max_pool(output,
                     ksize=[1, np.ceil(shape[1] * 1. / l).astype(np.int32), np.ceil(shape[2] * 1. / l).astype(np.int32), 1],
                     strides=[1, np.floor(shape[1] * 1. / l + 1).astype(np.int32), np.floor(shape[2] * 1. / l + 1), 1],
                          padding='SAME')
```

TypeError: Expected int32, got 1.0 of type 'float' instead.

Do you have any idea, how to deal with it?

Answer (score 1):

In your strides parameter, change the 3rd value to integer.
i.e.

`np.floor(shape[2] * 1. / l + 1)` to `np.floor(shape[2] * 1. / l + 1).astype(np.int32)`

Complete `stride` option:

```
strides=[1, np.floor(shape[1] * 1. / l + 1).astype(np.int32), 
           np.floor(shape[2] * 1. / l + 1).astype(np.int32), 1],
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: thanks for your answer. what you figure out is a problem.
but the true error raise at the point:

File "F:/MyProgram/Python/DL/SppNet.py", line 343, in SgdSppNet
    ksize=[1, np.ceil(shape[1] * 1. / l).astype(np.int32),

the length is a tf.tensor,not a constant.but the tf.nn.max_pool dosen't support variable as ksize or strides.